# removeObjectAtIndex: corrupting collection

Tags: ios, objective-c

EDIT: It was a problem in LLDB. I Changed to GDB and it's working.

Something strange is happening when I try to remove an object from a NSMutableArray in my app.
Prior to removal I have the following state in Xcode debugger

```
openList    NSMutableArray *    0x07563740
[0] SHAPathNode *   0x071846c0
[1] SHAPathNode *   0x07184c60
```

Then I perform:

```
[openList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

and get this corrupted collection

```
openList    NSMutableArray *    0x07563740
[0] id  0x00000000
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: some more context wouldn't hurt

Comment: Thanks Chuck. I did looked out for problems with NSMutableArray prior to posting the question but all I could find was crashing and access rights problems. Thanks for pointing that one out, it fixed it. How should I proceed now? Should I leave the question here, add a solution pointing to other thread?

Comment: Just leave it here and the question will be soon closed as duplicate